# Make container of absolute links be variable and not stretch the full height of viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header with a menu that drops down. The menu then has children/grandchilden links that slide in from the right. The problem I'm facing is that if the children/grandchildren section is longer than the original top-level section, then those extra links are cut off. For example, in my demo under "Services" you can only see Children 1-4 even though I have 6 children. **Is there a way to fix this WITHOUT making the nav ul be 100vh?** I want the container height to only be as tall as it needs to be so that it stretches/shrinks depending on how many links are visible at that time.

Because I had to add the overflow: hidden, I had to hide the scrollbar. I don't want users to scroll inside the menu. I want the menu to show all the child links without any scrolling.

*The link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/shawnkauffman/pen/bGEOBxE (Here in the codepen, I have the nav ul set to be `height: 100vh` so that the links are cut off but I don't want this container to stretch the height of the viewport.*

I also have the code pasted down below.

The code I have:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

header.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
}

.section-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 298px;
  background: #3E7D99;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-inner {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.parent-category {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #A89968;
  border: 0;
  height: 70px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

li {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  .next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

ul ul {
  transform: translateX(298px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  width: 298px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #3E7D99;
  .back {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.has-children.active>ul {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.has-grandchildren.active>ul {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

ul ul li {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.back-in-place {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.is-closed {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.children>li:first-of-type,
.grandchildren>li:first-of-type {
  background: #072258;
  &:hover {
    background: #072258;
  }
}

.children li:hover {
  background: #336C86;
}
```

```html
<header class="fixed">
  <div class="section-tab">
    <button class="expand">SECTION MENU (Click)</button>
    <div class="tab-inner">
      <div class="parent-category"><a href="#">Admissions & Aid</a></div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">About</a> <span class="next">></span>
          <ul class="children is-closed">
            <li><a href="#">About Children 1</a>
              <span class="back">
                                < </span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Children 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Services</a> <span class="next">></span>
          <ul class="children is-closed">
            <li><a href="#">Children 1</a>
              <span class="back">
                                < </span>
            </li>
            <li class="has-grandchildren">
              <a href="#">Children 2</a> <span class="next">></span>
              <ul class="grandchildren is-closed">
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 1</a>
                  <span class="back">
                                        < </span>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchildren 10</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

There might be some JavaScript I can write that will fix this but I'm hoping there's a way to do it with CSS.

Comment: Seems you already found a solution yourself, right? At least your CSS code reads `ul.nav { //height: 100vh; }`.

Comment: Yeah I found a way around it using JavaScript to calculate the height of the <ul>. Not ideal but it works.